# Opening a new form

Tags: tkinter

I have an application that I am using a keypad with.  I'm using the pad4pi library. On the main form I have a button that opens a second form.  The second form is its own class name nform.  I have imported the class for the new form from the filename newform.  In the main form I have a function called opennewform.  The buttons command is self.opennewform.  The button works all day long.  I press it and the new form shows.  As I capture keys from the keypad, I have one assigned to open the new form. When I press that key, the key is captured and a call is made to the same function opennewform. My problem is, sometimes the form doesn't actually show, sometimes it does when using the keypad.

```
from newform import nform

def opennewform(self):
    nform(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

I may not know why it does what it does, but I found a work around.  I just hid the button on the form and when the correct keypad button is pressed, I call the button.invoke().  Works every time now.